# Jquery `trigger` call handling lazily

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have a piece of code using `JQuery` that listens to initialization event on a DOM element.

```js
var $button = $("#myButton")

$button.on("init", function () {
 console.log("Hello")
})

$button.trigger("init")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myButton">Hello</div>
```

Notice how I registered the event listener first and then called the `trigger` function.

Now, I want my event listener function to be called no matter when the trigger is called, i.e, if the trigger is called before I register the event listener, kind of like listening to a stream of events.

This code does not work:

```js
var $button = $("#myButton")

$button.trigger("init")

$button.on("init", function () {
 console.log("Hello")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myButton">Hello</div>
```

Is there a `JQuery` specific solution that is there which I am not aware of?

Comment: No, you can't trigger an event without creating one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so like mentioned in the comments, you can't and shouldn't trigger an event before creating a lister.

BUT here is a quick hacky solution I've put together (because why not ¯\_(ツ)_/¯)

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/9mj86r5e/

Add the below code and replace `$button.trigger("init")` with `$button._trigger("init")`

```
/**
 * Create a callable trigger alternative
 * @param   {String}    name
 * @param   {Mixed}     ...params       Addition paramaters to send with event
 */
$.fn._trigger = function(name, ...params) {
    var $el = this;

        // Keep looping every 100ms until the event listner is found
    $el.myEventFinder = setInterval(function() {
        // Get an object of attached event listeners
        var events = $._data($el.get(0), 'events');

        // Has the event been found?
        if (events[name]) {
                // Stop the eventFinder loop
            clearInterval($el.myEventFinder);
            // Trigger event
            $el.trigger(name, ...params);
        }
    }, 100);
};
```

**P.s please don't use this code.** Just because it's doable, doesn't mean it should be done.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I don't think this is going to pass the code review :D.